# Saving and loading a KMeans clustering model with transfer learning

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, k-means, transfer-learning

I have the following KMeans clustering model in Python that runs on just about 5000 images which are unlabelled. I would like to save the model(s) and load it in a separate python script to simply feed it 1 image so that I can see which cluster that image is part of. The problem arises with saving and loading the model, I am not sure if it is done correctly as I am only saving the `kmodel` in a pickle file.

```
height = 299
width = 299
input_dir = "D:\\Glenn\\CNN\\Data\\Images"
glob_dir = input_dir + '/*.png'
images = [cv2.resize(cv2.imread(file), (height, width)) for file in glob.glob(glob_dir)]
paths = [file for file in glob.glob(glob_dir)]
images = np.array(np.float64(images))

model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(include_top=False, weights = "imagenet", input_shape=(height, width, 3))
predictions = model.predict(images.reshape(-1, height, width, 3))
pred_images = predictions.reshape(images.shape[0], -1)

k = 30
kmodel = KMeans(n_clusters = k, n_jobs=-1, random_state=728)
kmodel.fit(pred_images)
kpredictions = kmodel.predict(pred_images)
```

In general I'm a bit confused as to what I am doing is even optimal. I've found the optimal number of clusters using the silhouette method. But I am unsure how exactly to save and load this model in a separate python file to only predict what cluster 1 image will be in.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract topics from trained tomotopy HDP model and then initialize the kmeans clusterer to the number of topics automatically computed by the HDP.